# Jest testPathPattern only matching first file

Tags: jestjs, jest-client

I have following tests

```
 libs/app1/e2e/my-e2e-tests.spec.ts
 libs/app1/uat/my-uat-test.spec.ts
 libs/app2/e2e/my-e2e-tests.spec.ts
 libs/app2/uat/my-uat-test.spec.ts
```

I want a command to run all uat and e2e tests under libs/app1. Tried the following
`jest --testPathPattern=libs/app1/**/*.spec.ts`

But above command only run the first match which is 'libs/app1/e2e/my-e2e-tests.spec.ts'.

I also tried to provide a regular expression
`jest --testPathPattern=/libs\/app1\/[a-z]*\/[a-z]*.spec.ts/ig`

Answer (score 1):

`testPathPattern` uses a regexp pattern, not a glob pattern. Remove the `/**/*.spec.ts` part.

Try (*macOS*):

```bash
 $ npx jest --testPathPattern=libs/app1
 PASS  libs/app1/e2e/my-e2e-tests.spec.ts
 PASS  libs/app1/uat/my-uat-test.spec.ts

Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.685 s, estimated 20 s
Ran all test suites matching /libs\/app1/i.
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. This way it is running all the tests under app1. But i forgot one detail in my question. I don't want all tests under app1 to be ran. Only tests with file name ending in '.canary.spec.ts' needs to be picked. I am not sure how that regular expression would be

Comment: I got a solution that works now. Using 'runTestsByPath' and 'testPathPattern'

--runTestsByPath=llibs/app1/ --testPathPattern .canary.spec.ts